# Using ICE & TURN with twilio video

Tags: twilio

It is not immediately obvious how one would go about adding Network Traversal Service if you are using Twilio Video.

The example of using the **Network Traversal Service** [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/stun-turn) shows token creation using :

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.tokens.create({}, function(err, token) {
    process.stdout.write(token.username);
});
```

However the basic **video** example [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/identity) shows a completely different method of token creation using the AccessToken lib.

```
var token = new AccessToken(
        process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
        process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
        process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) service actually uses the [Network Traversal Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/stun-turn) under the hood, so you don't need to worry about adding it in yourself. The `AccessToken` method is the most up to date version of granting access to the client side SDKs, so I would continue to use that.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: OK in that case, (as I am not getting through some firewalls) are there any ports I need to request be opened or URLs to whitelist etc... Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Do you have any logs you can share which show the problems you're having with those firewalls?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I will be able to get some tomorrow which should hopefully illustrate the problem. The firewall belongs to a school so it quite secure.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah schools can be like that. It's probably best to send logs to [Twilio Support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they'll be able to help out.